# Checking service history i.e. full service not mot

Tags: service

For any vehicle you need to get an MOT done annually then there's a Service every so often.

I know the dvla has a tool for checking it's MOT status.

However how do I know the previous owner of van has had it regularly serviced as per manufacturer standards? I am talking about a full service not just MOT.

Comment: This is going to be nearly impossible to tell. *IF* (and that's a big IF) the previous owner had all of the maintenance done at the dealership, you might be able to find record of it. However, if the previous owner did the maintenance themselves or if they had a smaller shop do it, which doesn't keep online records, you're not going to find anything. Realistically, a used car is a used car, so you take your chances. You check what you can check and hope for the best.

Comment: You ask the previous owner to show you the service history. If he/she can't do that, assume it's never been serviced! If the previous owner *did* get it serviced "to manufacturer standards" then he/she should  be able get a duplicate copy of the history from the garage that did the work - it's not *your* job to go chasing after the end of a rainbow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service history booklet within the vehicles document pack has spaces for servicing workshops to stamp their official stamp and record the mileage and date so this is the first place to check.

Also look through any receipts that the vendor has with the vehicle.

If there is no paper evidence of servicing, assume it hasn’t been serviced and adjust your offer accordingly.